# Can we assign record type to profile using apex programming?

Tags: apex

Can we assign particular record types to profiles using Apex? My scenario is , if we select profile and record type, then that record type is automatically assigned to that particular profile using apex.

I am getting profile and record type ID using the following SOQL queries,

```
[SELECT id,name,SObjectType from RecordType]
[SELECT Id,name FROM Profile]
```

but i can't update profile with record type.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Financial Force's [Metadata API Wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to access the metadata API. You'd need to use the Metadata API to assign record types to profiles, because this is not a normal type of metadata that you can update directly.